# Live Location using Python

Tags: python, gps, location, geopy, geocoder

I had to get live location using for an emergency service idea me and a group of friends had. I tried using geopy and geocoder but the location was far off from my actual one.

The code i tried is attached below:

```
import geocoder
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

g = geocoder.ip('me')
coors = g.latlng

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_app_name")
location = geolocator.reverse(f"{coors[0]}, {coors[1]}")

print(location.address)
```

The location it provided me with a location about 200kms(124.274 miles) away from my actual location.
Is it possible to get the intended output from the modules I used or are there any better ones out there?

Comment: Some APIs will allow you to get more precise location data if they have snooped your wireless router's SSID.

Comment: IP geolocation is nowhere near the accuracy you need for any kind of emergency service.

Comment: I am kinda new to this stuff could u tell me a way without ip geolocation?